# Sparse column size limitation workaround

Tags: sql, sql-server, mongodb, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL server 2014. I'm creating multiple tables, always with more than 500 columns, which will be varying accordingly.

So, I created a sparse column so that I could be sure if the number of my columns exceed 1024 there won't be a problem. Now there is a new problem:

> Cannot create a row that has sparse data of size 8710 which is greater
>   than the allowable maximum sparse data size of 8023.

I know SQL server allows only 8 Kb of data in a row, I need to know what's the work around for this. If I need to plan to move to No SQL (Mongodb) how much impact will it create on converting my stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum number of columns in an ordinary table is 1024. Maximum number of columns in a wide (sparse) table is 30,000. Sparse columns are usually used when you have a lot of columns, but most of them are `NULL`.

In any case, there is [limit of 8060 bytes per row](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx), so sparse columns won't help.

Often, having thousand columns in a table indicate that there are problems with the database design and normalisation.

If you are sure that you need these thousand values as columns, not as rows in a related table, then the only workaround that comes to mind is to partition the table vertically.

For example, you have a `Table1` with column `ID` (which is the primary key) and 1000 other columns. Split it into `Table1` and `Table2`. Each will have the same `ID` as a primary key and 500 columns each. The tables would be linked 1:1 using foreign key constraint.

Comment: Agreed, but the thing is i have only 863 columns in the table for now. but it is throwing error.

Comment: The limit that you are hitting is not the number of columns, but 8060 bytes per row. The only workaround that I can think of is to split the table vertically into several tables with less bytes per row.

Comment: That is too costly by means of time and effort, or is there any way i could move the table to a nosql database and use the sql stored procedure?

Comment: @user2956568, sorry I don't know anything about nosql database.

Comment: Anyways, Cheers mate.

Answer (score 0):

The datatypes that are used and the density of how much data in a row is null determines the effectiveness of sparse columns. If all of the fields in a table are populated there is actually more overhead on storing those rows and will cause you to hit that maximum page size faster. If that is the case then don't use sparse columns.

See how many you can convert from static to variable length datatypes (varchar, nvarchar, varbinary). This might buy you some additional space in the page as variable length fields can be put into overflow pages, but do carry an overhead of 24 bytes for the pointer into the overflow page. I suspect you were thinking that sparse columns was going to allow you to store 30K columns...this would only be the circumstance where you had a wide table where most of the columns are NULL.

MongoDB will not be your answer...at least not without a lot of refactoring. You will not be able to leverage your existing stored procedures. It might be the best fit for you but there are many things to consider when moving to MongoDB. Your data access layer will need to be rebuilt unless you just happen to be persisting your data in the relational structure as JSON documents :). I assume that is not the case.

I am assuming that you have wide tables and they are densely populated...based on that assumption here is my recommendation.

Partition the table as Vladimir suggested, but create a view that will join all these tables together to make it look like one table. Now you have the same structure as you did before. Then add an Instead of Trigger to the view to update the tables. This is a way that you can get what you want without having to do major refactoring of your code. There is code you need to add for the trigger, but my experience as been that it's easy to write and most times I didn't write the code but created a script to generate the code for all the views I had to do this for since it was repetitive.